# How to write multiple things to console at once?

Tags: c#, console, console.writeline

```
int a=10,b=20;

console.writeline(a);
console.writeline(b);
```

I want to use only one console.writeline();

I use code below but doesn't work

```
console.writeline(a,b);
```

Comment: In the future, please use a meaningful question title (I have removed your emoticons) and format your code using the formatting tools in the editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
Console.Writeline("{0}{1}", a, b);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", a, b));
```

Comment: WriteLine already support format method, you don't need to call string.format

Comment: Even though Console.WriteLine supports arguments, this is still a correct answer